# Algebraic number theory problem

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Can anyone provide me a source to learn algebraic number theory via solving problems which has solutions available too?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but Milne's book https://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf contains solutions to many of its exercises.

Comment: The book "Algebraic Number Theory" by Neukirch is a good introductory book with lots of details.

Comment: [M. Ram Murty, J. Esmonde, *Problems in Algebraic Number Theory*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387221823) springs to mind. The first 150 pages or so are theory, examples and exercise. The remaining 200 pages are for solutions.

Comment: Thanks all of you.. Ram murthy's book will be better for solving problems I think so.. I asked this because I wanted to have a book which clears concepts via problem solving like Ram murthy's analytic number theory..If it is there for algebraic number theory too I think it would be helpful